# Creating a admin controller using adminhtml id

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I'm trying to add a controller accessible on admin menu through url:
https://dev.m2t2.com/admin_k1tgag/admin/helloWorld/index/key/0195fab99cc865bb756a77e8fe5ceedb6f8eee97de91d569398d383cef4f0d81/

Generated by the XML code  inserted below. But it keeps returning

> Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.

Router.xml :

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="adminhtml">
            <module name="Study_Admin" before="Magento_Backend"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

In menu i inserted:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Study_Admin::greetings" title="Greetings" translate="title" module="Study_Admin" parent="Magento_Backend::content" sortOrder="50" dependsOnModule="Study_Admin" resource="Study_Admin::greetings"/>
        <add id="Study_Admin::greetings_helloworld" title="Hello World" translate="title" module="Study_Admin" parent="Study_Admin::greetings" sortOrder="10" dependsOnModule="Study_Admin" action="adminhtml/helloWorld" resource="Study_Admin::greetings"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

But when i access  the controller through the menu i have no success. I started debugging and i checked that non-custom controllers extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action class to pass validations inside magento routing core flow. I did the same but i still have no success.

Below my controller class:

```php
<?php


namespace Study\Controller\Adminhtml\HelloWorld;



use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use ‌Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    const MENU_Id = "Study_Admin::greetings_helloworld";
    protected $resultPageFActory;
    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFActory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFActory = $resultPageFActory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFActory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu(static::MENU_Id);
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Hello World'));
        return $resultPage;
        // TODO: Implement execute() method.
    }


}
```

The file structure is :
[image]

Thanx in advance, and take care.

Answer (score 0):

It works... was just my namespace in Controller's class that had an error

'namespace Study\Admin\Controller\Adminhtml\Helloworld;'